# Superannuation investment over 25 years

Tags: investing, payment, superannuation

I'm wondering if anyone would have any idea, .. I had a small super account with a (major) Superannuation provider.  I believe that it had a few thousand dollars in it.  Now I come back and check after 25 years, and the amount they turned into the ATO (after 20 years of me not contributing) was $3784.00.
Would this be a fair amount?  After 25 years on investing?

I've also approached them about receiving some sort of account statement, but they have not been forthcoming..

Answer (score 2):

The problem with small super account balances is that any annual returns would usually be eaten up by fees, especially if it was a retail fund (which usually have higher fees).

That is why the best thing to do is to roll over any small super accounts into your main super account. If you change jobs you can either roll over your previous super account into your new one, or these days you can tell your new employer to contribute to your existing super account.

With regards to fees, in general, industry super funds will usually have lower fees than retail super fund, and often they have been producing better returns as well.